# Reading dotenv variables in a yaml file in a node project

Tags: yaml, cucumberjs, dotenv, browserstack

I'm using Cucumber-js to run tests on browserstack. I'm pretty new to it all, but I'm trying to use dotenv to store the credentials and have my yaml read from the environment variables. It works if I hardcode the credentials so the project itself seems fine.

The project is barebones, just a single feature, step file and hook file.

I have a browserstack.yml

```yaml
userName: ${BROWSERSTACK_USERNAME}
accessKey: ${BROWSERSTACK_ACCESS_KEY}
platforms:
  - os: Windows
    osVersion: 11
    browserName: Chrome
    browserVersion: 115.0
parallelsPerPlatform: 1
browserstackLocal: false
buildName: bstack-demo
buildIdentifier: ${BUILD_NUMBER}
projectName: BrowserStack Sample
testObservability: false
networkLogs: false
consoleLogs: info
```

and my .env looks like this

```
BROWSERSTACK_USERNAME=thing1
BROWSERSTACK_ACCESS_KEY=thing2
```

My dependencies are as such:

```json
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "@cucumber/cucumber": "^9.3.0",
    "assert": "^2.0.0",
    "browserstack-node-sdk": "^1.24.2",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "geckodriver": "^4.1.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "selenium-webdriver": "^4.10.0"
  }
}
```

I've also tried to run a variety of dotenv initializers from my hook before I initiate the web driver for my tests as early as possible but sadly still nothing.

```js
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config();
```

The error I get it

```
WebDriverError: Invalid username or password
    at Object.checkLegacyResponse (/Users/user/project/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:558:15)
    at parseHttpResponse (/Users/user/project/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:593:13)
    at Executor.execute (/Users/user/project/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:529:28)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    Then a thing - SKIPPED
    After - PASSED
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `BROWSERSTACK_USERNAME=thing1 BROWSERSTACK_ACCESS_KEY=thing2 <test command>` which works for me instead of having it stored in a .env file.